# ERROR: filesystem layer verification failed for digest sha256 Mac

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose

Im new to Docker and followed very simple steps in my Mac(Intel Version). Downloaded Docker and moved to applications. Post that, I have tried docker-compse for almost 10 different images available from docker website. No matter which images, I always end at the error ***filesystem layer verification failed for digest sha256***

I have tried few solutions which are out there. But none have resolved the issue.

Appreciate any help from the community here!

Additional Details -
Mac OS: Catalina 10.15.7
Docker Version: 20.10.16
Docker-compose Version: 1.29.2

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this?